# How to load a svg image into tab header in Xamarin

Tags: svg, xamarin.forms, tabs

I'm building a simple application which has 3 tabs, every tab have an icon and a text.
The sample project that I'm basing my code exists here:

[link](https://github.com/vladpoint/TabbedPageWithNavigationPage)

The only problem that I found with it, it uses pixilated images for the tab headers which I would like to change to SVG resource files.

I added a FFImageLoading library and added the svg support from here

[link](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/SVG-support)

I managed to add an image to one of the tab content pages but I don't see the svg image that I'm trying to see in the header.

This is my code so far:

**TodayPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class TodayPage : ContentPage
    {
        public TodayPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeComponent();
            // IconImageSource = "today.png"; <-- this will show the pixilated image
            IconImageSource = SvgImageSource.FromResource("today.svg"); //<--not working
            Title = "Today";
        }
    }
```

**TodayPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"
             x:Class="TabsApp.TodayPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <forms:SvgCachedImage WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200" Source="resource://TabsApp.Resources.today.svg"/>
            <Label Text="Today's appointments go here going" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabsApp;assembly=TabsApp" 
            x:Class="TabsApp.MainPage">
    <local:TodayPage />
    <NavigationPage Title="Schedule" IconImageSource="schedule.png">
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:SchedulePage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
    <local:SettingPage />
</TabbedPage>
```

Thank you

**Edit**

Thanks to Leon I managed to load svg file in Android.
I'm still struggling to load svg file in iOS.

I managed to create a custom tab renderer in iOS here is the code:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabPage), typeof(PageTabRenderer))]
    namespace TabsApp.iOS
{
    [Foundation.Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    public class PageTabRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        protected override async Task<Tuple<UIImage, UIImage>> GetIcon(Page page)
        {
            var navigationPage = page as NavigationPage;
            if (navigationPage != null && navigationPage.CurrentPage != null)
            {
                var imageSource = navigationPage.IconImageSource == null ? navigationPage.CurrentPage.IconImageSource : navigationPage.IconImageSource;
                return await this.GetNativeUIImage(imageSource);
            }

            return await this.GetNativeUIImage(page.IconImageSource);
        }

        private async Task<Tuple<UIImage, UIImage>> GetNativeUIImage(ImageSource imageSource)
        {
            var imageicon = await GetNativeImageAsync(imageSource);
            return new Tuple<UIImage, UIImage>(imageicon, null);
        }

        private async Task<UIImage> GetNativeImageAsync(ImageSource imageSource)
        {
            if (imageSource is FileImageSource fileImage && fileImage.File.Contains(".svg"))
            {
                var imageicon = await ImageService.Instance.LoadFile(fileImage.File).WithCustomDataResolver(new SvgDataResolver(15, 15, true)).AsUIImageAsync();
                return imageicon.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
            }
            
            else
            {
                var imageicon = await GetUIImage(imageSource);
                return imageicon.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
            }
        }
        
        private Task<UIImage> GetUIImage(ImageSource imageSource)
        {
            var handler = GetImageSourceHandler(imageSource);
            return handler.LoadImageAsync(imageSource);
        }

        private static IImageSourceHandler GetImageSourceHandler(ImageSource source)
        {
            IImageSourceHandler sourceHandler = null;
            if (source is UriImageSource)
                sourceHandler = new ImageLoaderSourceHandler();
            else if (source is FileImageSource)
                sourceHandler = new FileImageSourceHandler();
            else if (source is StreamImageSource)
                sourceHandler = new StreamImagesourceHandler();
            else if (source is FontImageSource)
                sourceHandler = new FontImageSourceHandler();

            return sourceHandler;
        }
      
        
        
    }
    
}
```

this is my mainpage.xaml

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabsApp;assembly=TabsApp" 
            x:Class="TabsApp.MainPage">
    <local:TodayPage />
    <NavigationPage Title="Schedule" IconImageSource="today1.svg">
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:SchedulePage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
    <local:SettingPage />
</TabbedPage>
```

I also copied TabPage class but I don't see the svg icons loading. I tried to debug it and it seems the GetIcon is never called.

****** **Edit 2** *******

After more playing with the code here and there I managed to figure it out. If someone will be interested in implementing similar design

**main.xaml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<custom:TabPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabsApp;assembly=TabsApp"
                xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:TabsApp.custom;assembly=TabsApp"
                x:Class="TabsApp.MainPage"
                xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
                android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
                android:TabbedPage.IsSmoothScrollEnabled="True"
                android:TabbedPage.IsSwipePagingEnabled="False"
                xmlns:iOS="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
                xmlns:ffimageloadingsvg="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"
                iOS:Page.UseSafeArea="true" NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
                BarTextColor="{DynamicResource SecondaryTextColor}" UnselectedTabColor="Black" SelectedTabColor="Blue"
                NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False">
   
   
            <local:TodayPage IconImageSource="{x:OnPlatform Android=ic_today, iOS=today-24px.svg}"/>
   
    
   
            <local:SchedulePage IconImageSource="{x:OnPlatform Android=ic_schedule, iOS=schedule-24px.svg}"/>
      
  
            <local:SettingPage IconImageSource="{x:OnPlatform Android=ic_settings, iOS=settings-24px.svg}"/>
     
    
</custom:TabPage>
```

It's important to note two things: IconImageSource will be changed depending on the platform, SelectedTabColor will be the tint color for both Android and iOS when a tab item is selected.

you need to convert the svg files to drawable vector files just like Lean wrote and put them in /drawable folder.

As for iOS you will need to add a custom tab renderer this is the one I used:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabPage), typeof(PageTabRenderer))]
namespace TabsApp.iOS
{
    [Foundation.Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    public class PageTabRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        readonly nfloat imageYOffset = 7.0f;

        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            if (TabBar.Items != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in TabBar.Items)
                {
                    item.Title = null;
                    item.ImageInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(imageYOffset, 0, -imageYOffset, 0);
                }
            }
        }
        
        protected override async Task<Tuple<UIImage, UIImage>> GetIcon(Page page)
        {
            var navigationPage = page as NavigationPage;
            if (navigationPage != null && navigationPage.CurrentPage != null)
            {
                var imageSource = navigationPage.IconImageSource == null ? navigationPage.CurrentPage.IconImageSource : navigationPage.IconImageSource;
                return await this.GetNativeUIImage(imageSource);
            }

            return await this.GetNativeUIImage(page.IconImageSource);
        }

        private async Task<Tuple<UIImage, UIImage>> GetNativeUIImage(ImageSource imageSource)
        {
            var imageicon = await GetNativeImageAsync(imageSource);
            return new Tuple<UIImage, UIImage>(imageicon, null);
        }

        private async Task<UIImage> GetNativeImageAsync(ImageSource imageSource)
        {
            if (imageSource is FileImageSource fileImage && fileImage.File.Contains(".svg"))
            {
                var imageicon = await ImageService.Instance.LoadFile(fileImage.File).WithCustomDataResolver(new SvgDataResolver(15, 15, true)).AsUIImageAsync();
                return imageicon.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.Automatic);
            }
            
            else
            {
                var imageicon = await GetUIImage(imageSource);
                return imageicon.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
            }
        }
        
        private Task<UIImage> GetUIImage(ImageSource imageSource)
        {
            var handler = GetImageSourceHandler(imageSource);
            return handler.LoadImageAsync(imageSource);
        }

        private static IImageSourceHandler GetImageSourceHandler(ImageSource source)
        {
            IImageSourceHandler sourceHandler = null;
            if (source is UriImageSource)
                sourceHandler = new ImageLoaderSourceHandler();
            else if (source is FileImageSource)
                sourceHandler = new FileImageSourceHandler();
            else if (source is StreamImageSource)
                sourceHandler = new StreamImagesourceHandler();
            else if (source is FontImageSource)
                sourceHandler = new FontImageSourceHandler();

            return sourceHandler;
        }
      
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Put all the *.svg files in the /Resources folder in *.iOS folder and that's it.

Comment: today.svg is added as an embedded resource correct?  (sorry for the obvious question but just checking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same result, here is my workaround for svg image in the tabbed bar.

For android, please visit this page
https://shapeshifter.design/

Then import your SVG file to the website, then download the xml file, like following operation(click `Import`, select `svg`, choose the svg file, then select `Export`, Vector the drawable, download the xml file). Copy the xml file to the Android `Resource/ Drawable` folder(please check the build Action is `AndroidResource` of xml file). Note: if you want to change the line color of svg file, please open the xml, fond the fill color, change it.

[image]

[image]

Then you can use it in the pcl XML like following code.

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App3" xmlns:ffimageloadingsvg="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"
            BarBackgroundColor="Green"
            x:Class="App3.MainPage">


    <local:TodayPage IconImageSource="{x:OnPlatform Android=ic_today,iOS=today.svg}"  >
      
    </local:TodayPage>
    <NavigationPage Title="Schedule" IconImageSource="myIcon.png">
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:Page1 />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
    
</TabbedPage>
```

Here is running screenshot.

[image]

For IOS, please refer to the `Dinesh_Official`'s reply in this thread:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/179773/how-to-use-svg-image-for-tabbed-page-tabbar-icon

Comment: The android solution worked for me, I'm still not sure how to implement the iOS variation and also how to differentiate between android and iOS when it comes to loading different resources/renders

Comment: Lean Lu, Do I need to create tab renderer for every tab that I will have?

Comment: @DemoDemo In IOS, you should create an custom renderer for your Tabbedpage, then override the `GetIcon` method, here is demo code.https://github.com/dinesh4official/XFPage/blob/master/XFPage/XFPage.iOS/Mapping/PageTabRenderer.cs. You also could download it.

Comment: I updated my question, it seems like GetIcon is never called. I attached my new code in the original post. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

For debugging SVGS, here are some steps that may help.

1. Will a different confirmed working SVG work if you replaced it? If not is ffimageloading initialized?
2. Confirm your embedded resources.  (place this in App.xaml.cs)

```
    public static void PrintEmbeddedResources()
    {
        #if DEBUG
        var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        var logTxt = "Embedded Resources:" + Environment.NewLine;
        foreach (var res in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("found resource: " + res);
        }
        #endif
    }
```

3. validate that your svg is optimised.  Here is a tool ffimageloading recommends: https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/
4. ffimageloading sometimes has problems with specific SVGS.
   Check the Issues on their github to see if someone else has reported a problem similar to you and *hopefully* posted a work around.

Comment: 1. I'm not sure if they are optimized I downloaded one from here https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline
2. The resource is embedded resource, I can see it in debug entering the loop with the right name.
3. I used CachedImageRenderer.Init(true);
            var ignore = typeof(SvgCachedImage); 
like in the wiki of ffimageloading